# Passing variable or setting a variable by URL in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, url, typescript

I have an application written in Angular2. In one component, there's a chart, you can adjust it by setting few variables. I would like the user to have completely set chart with these variables already set by the URL link.

For example: `localhost:4200/app/chart?height=500;width=400;color=blue`

Inside my component, there are variables called:

```
this.height: number;
this.width: number;
this.color: string;
```

And that is my question, how can I set them exactly from the URL link, on component load? (on init)

And my second question, how can I pass these variables into URL? For example, I have these variables:

```
this.height: number = 500;
this.width: number = 400;
this.color: string = blue;
```

How can I send them to the URL? To make it look like:

```
localhost:4200/app/chart?height=500;width=400;color=blue`
```

My routing file:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ChartComponent } from './chart/chart/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'app', component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'chart', component: ChartComponent },
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
    ]},

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
 ];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Can you please paste your route configuration? I think your answer lies in the `@angular/router` namespace :)

Comment: @A1rPun Done my friend

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        this.height: number = params['height'];
        this.width: number = params['width'];
        this.color: string = params['color'];
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where to drop it? In routing file or my chart component?

Comment: In your component where you use it. And dont forget the import `import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
`

Comment: No this use the current URL route path

Comment: What if I want to send these variables to the url? Not only download?

Comment: @J.Doe `this.router.navigate(['/chart', this.height, this.width, this.color]);`

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks, Nicolas is going great today and I don't want to stop him :) I hope he will update his answer with more info *hinthint*

Comment: There are different ways to accomplish this but simplest would be `this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { height: 100, width: 200, color: "red" }]);`